# Better way to invert cases of characters in a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

As a novice Java programmer who barely got started in Java programming, I am totally exhausted in trying to find a solution to this issue. A course that I am currently studying gave homework that asked me to create a Java class that has a sort of “reverse” method that returns a new version of the string
of the current string where the capitalization is reversed (i.e., lowercase to uppercase
and uppercase to lowercase) for the alphabetical characters specified in a given condition. Say if I were to reverse “abc, XYZ; 123.” using reverse("bcdxyz@3210."), it must return "aBC, xyz; 123.". (P.S: the class ignores numbers and special characters and the variable "myString" is where the "abc, XYZ; 123." goes to.). So far, I've only managed to return out "aBC, XYZ; 123." with the code below. Am I missing something here?

```
public String reverse(String arg) {
    // TODO Implement method 
    String arg_no_sym = arg.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
    String arg_perfect = arg_no_sym.replaceAll("\\d","");
    
    if (myString != null) {
        char[] arrayOfReplaceChars = arg_perfect.toCharArray();
        char[] arrayOfmyString = myString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arg_perfect.length(); i++) {
            myString = myString.replace(String.valueOf((arrayOfReplaceChars[i])), String.valueOf((arrayOfReplaceChars[i])).toUpperCase()); 
        }
        return myString;
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `myString`?

Comment: The variable where the “abc, XYZ; 123.” goes to.

Comment: You don't need to convert your strings to arrays: you can use `arg_perfect.charAt(i)` for example. You can also combine your regular expressions into `"[^a-zA-Z]"`. The issue that you are having is with taking characters to replace out of `arg_perfect`: at the moment, they are all lowercase; you should make sure that when doing the replacement, you replace both the lowercase and uppercase characters. Just think about special cases like `"aA"`, which should become `"Aa"`.

Comment: @Anfieldin21thCentury unless `myString` is a global or instance variable then your code will not run as the variable is not defined, so please provide the full code for a minimal working example :)

Comment: @BillyBrown Yes, that's what I need. But how is it possible to replace both lowercase and uppercase characters at the same time is my question.

Comment: @Anfieldin21thCentury One method is to iterate over the characters in `myString`, then see if that character (regardless of case) is in `arg_perfect`. If it is, then reverse its case using Shotokan's suggestion.

Comment: @BillyBrown Oh my god. I FINALLY did it! Thank you and everyone so much!

Comment: @Anfieldin21thCentury Can you replace your old code with your solution? Would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the methods `isUpperCase()` and `isLowerCase()` to check the case of the letters and then use `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` to change the case of them?

Comment: Note, that these methods are `static` in the `java.lang.Character` class